# What's the recommended way to do database migrations with Ktor + Exposed (Kotlin)?

Tags: sql, database, kotlin, migration

The Ktor or Exposed frameworks do not have any built-in support for database migrations. What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: The database migration depends on the database, not on the web framework, right?

Comment: Correct, I've edited the question to clarify the Ktor + Exposed (DB library) stack.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Ktor with Gradle I would recommend using Flyway programatically inside the entry point of your Application. This way it could easily be a part of your Continuous Delivery pipeline. You can see the Flyway docs using API here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/

What I essentially do though is add the dependency (using Kotlin DSL):

```
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.5.2")
```

And then all you need to do is create an instance of Flyway and call migrate when you load your module:

```
fun Application.module() {

  Flyway.configure().dataSource(/*config to your DB*/).load().migrate()

  //the rest of your application
  routing {

  }
}
```

You could of course extract the creation of Flyway to your DI tool (e.g. Koin) and add some logging to show progress.

This way your DB will be migrated (if necessary) every time just before your app is started.

As for writing up the actual migration [the official docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/firststeps/api#creating-the-first-migration) are very helpful. What you essentially need to do is:

1. Make sure you have the required directory for migration files - `src/main/resources/db/migration` by default ).
2. Write plain SQL in separate migration files in the above directory. The filenames need to stick to the convention too (by default: start with capital `V` then a number, which you will increment for each new migration, **double underscore** - this tricked me at the beginning ;) - and a snake_case description, e.g. `V1__Create_person_table.sql`)
3. Run the app and observe magic :D

Comment: While this answer is helpful (and I've upvoted it) it doesn't give much reference on how to provide migrations to flyway (which I'd very much like to have in this answer)

Comment: good point, thanks @SomerandomITboy ! I've just updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

> Database tables are migrated at deployment via Flyway and scripts can be added in db/migrations folder to add new tables or execute queries like inserting data etc on server startup.
>   (https://github.com/arun0009/kotlin-ktor-exposed-sample-api)

Here's how Flyway works: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how

1. Download, install, and configure Flyway (See https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline)
2. Point it to a database, which will be the location of flyway_schema_history
3. Write your migration files for create table or insert data following their naming convention: `V<version number>__<migration description>` and run with `flyway migrate`
4. Write your repeatable migration files for create view following their naming convention: `R__<migration description>` and run with `flyway migrate`
5. Write your undo migration files for drop table or delete data following their naming convention: `V<version number>__<migration description>` and run with `flyway migrate`
6. Check your migration status with `flyway info` and commit your files if you're happy
7. Make any necessary modifications are rerun migration. Repeat and commit.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I believe it's usually a good SO practice to include an explanation in your answer, e.g: How exactly is the proposed library set up, how it functions, how do we run migrations etc. (as your source also provides no explanation).

Comment: I'm trying to look for a way to avoid having to manually write migration files. Are you aware of any such solution which can automatically create migration files (perhaps by diffing two sql servers) or auto-magically update a DB schema? (A bit like how Django works, which provides a framework native way of doing this)

Comment: I've written a tutorial on how to integrate Flyway with Exposed: https://bettercoding.dev/kotlin/tutorial-exposed-generation-flyway/ Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In case if this is a one time activity, you can try using a Off-the shelf utility like [SQL Data Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

To make this happen, you would need to ensure that both the databases are accessible locally from your machine so that you can create 2 DB connections and run a comparison against them.

At the end of comparison, you can get a Auto-Generated SQL Script out of it to run against your new schema and make it sychronized.

In case if you wish to compare Schema Objects as well, again Red-Gate provides a similar [Schema Compare tool](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), which they have now started to call as SQL Compare (God knows why !!). This utility would also provide similar auto-generated script to help you.

But, again Red Gate is good for one-time migration and you can use this with their Trial version for a period of 30 days. For similar activity in regular basis, you would need to buy the Licensed version of same software.

Comment: Yes, I do know of that, but that is some price tag. Are you aware of any other free/FOSS/cheaper tools?

Comment: Other alternatives, could be like;
1. Schema Comparison can be achieved using SQL Developer --> Tools --> Database Diff.
2. For Data using a export / import method supported by your Database.

Also SQL Developer --> Tools --> Database Copy is another in-built alternative with SQL Developer tool. It copies Schema as well as Data, but then we would need to ensure that network connectivity is maintained.

Comment: Yep, I have tried this with Oracle Databases. Not sure if there is something similar supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For Data Migrantion, I use [Navicat Premium](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-premium) which i find very easy to use, but it is not an open source. If you are looking for an Open Source Tool, then You can use SQLines Data which is an open source (Apache License 2.0), scalable, parallel high performance data transfer and schema conversion tool that you can use for database migrations and ETL processes.

[SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/sqldata)

It is available for Linux, Windows, both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms.

You can also use SQLines Data for cross-platform database migration. The tool migrates table definitions, constraints, indexes and transfers data.

This how you can start with SQLines:

1. Download and unzip the file, no installation is required
2. Run sqldataw.exe on Windows to launch the GUI version
3. Run ./sqldata on Linux to launch the command line tool.

And There are Migration guidelines available for specific databases.[Guidelines](http://www.sqlines.com/download)